# Erro na função - Retorno vazio

Tags: php, funções

Esta função retorna vazia.. Qual o erro? Obrigado!

```
$id_pessoa = 1;

function nome_pessoa()
{

$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM equipe WHERE id='$id_pessoa' ");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        return $row["nome"];
    }

}   

echo nome_pessoa();
```

Comment: Na sua função não estão definidas as variáveis `$link` e `$id_pessoa`, provavelmente pelas configurações do seu servidor, esses erros foram omitidos.

Comment: O $link faz a função de conexão. O $id_pessoa eu nao posso puxar de outro lugar? como fiz ali em cima? Declarando como fixo ou entao por $_POST?

Comment: @RodrigoMendonça para ter acesso a uma variável que está fora do escopo da função, é necessário utilizar o [`global`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.scope.php) ou então passar a variável através de parâmetros da função, ex: `function nome_pessoa($link) { ... }` e para chamá-la: `echo nome_pessoa($link);`

Comment: Então, eu tinha feito o seguinte, e também apresentou erro:

$id_pessoa = 1;

function nome_pessoa($id_pessoa)
{

$sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM equipe WHERE id='$id_pessoa' ");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {
        return $row["nome"];
    }

}   

echo nome_pessoa($id_pessoa);

Apresentou os erros:

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in ...

Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in ...

Até então eu tinha ctz q iria funcionar.. Fiquei perdido pra resolver isso.

Comment: Alguma sugestao?

Answer (score 2):

Diferente de muitas outras linguagens de programação, variáveis que são definidas no escopo global não são importadas naturalmente para o escopo local. Assim, uma variável que é definida fora da função não estará definida dentro da função.

Basicamente o problema no seu código é utilizar variáveis que não estão definidas na função. Você pode contornar isso passando os valores por parâmetro:

```
function getNomePessoa(mysqli $link, int $id): ?string 
{
    if ($result = $link->query("SELECT * FROM equipe WHERE id='{$id}'")) {
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            return $row["nome"];
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Assim, basta você chamar a função passando devidamente os parâmetros:

```
$nome = getNomePessoa($link, $id_pessoa);
```

Comment: Anderson.. Muito obrigado pela explicação.. Tu é o cara.. Eu só estava precisando de uma explicação e um exemplo pra entender melhor como funciona, já que estou acostumado a usar outras formas.. Valeu mesmo.. Este tipo de ajuda é sempre muito valioso pra quem busca aprender.. Mais uma vez obrigado.